# Increasing collection level for performance counters in vCenter 5

Tags: vmware-esxi, performance-monitoring, vmware-vcenter

I want to simply increase the collection level of some of the Network performance counters to 4, when I look in performance for the host, and click 'Advanced', switch to look at the Network performance and then click 'Chart Options' I see the collection levels for the counters are all 1 or 2, how would I increase these to 4?

Comment: I don't believe that's available due to the impact on the database it would have, level 4 on anything massively increases volume. I just did a bit of googling for this myself and got nothing, maybe log a case with vmw? Great question for a new user by the way :)

Comment: Thanks a million Chopper3, I have been reading and googling on this myself for the last while and I believe you are correct, it doesnt look like it can be changed because of the impact it would have on the database.

Comment: Worth placing a call if you have a support contract, they WILL come back to you at some point, could be a while though.